# HTTP Error 414.0 - URL Too Long. But URL is short. IIS

Tags: windows, iis

The website is on IIS web server.
The physical path is a SYMLINKD pinted to UNC path.

The website not detect the default document but if put /index.aspx the web works.

The problem is not the URL long

Please, I need help
Fran

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. It was using pass through authentication which seemed to work fine for .aspx pages but not for any other file type, there are similar questions here you can use as reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69119855/13336642.

Comment: Yes, I've seen those answer. But I need more details to solve it.

The aspx pages not detect as default document.

Comment: You can try to give all permissions to the requested url path, and give all iis permissions to the UNC path.