# How to use long URL for a website

Tags: url, coldfusion

I am using a link on my site to open the same page and send all these form fields in the link URL. The link is used to show all data on the page which is in pagination.

My problem is the URL size is too large. When I deploy I am getting the below error for the on server, but on a local machine its working fine. How can I use a very long URL for my website?

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Comment: You might take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202257/design-restful-get-api-with-a-long-list-of-query-parameters

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you are using request filtering in IIS, this is not a Coldfusion specific issue. If your maximum query string length is currently set to a conservative value, you could increase it in IIS as per http://www.mdloring.com/2013/general/iis7-http-error-404-15-found-request-filtering-module-configured-deny-request-query-string-long/

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Internet Information Services
3. Select your web server on the right side
4. Double-Click Request Filtering under the IIS section
5. Click Edit Feature Settings on the right side menu
6. Increase the Maximum URL length (Bytes) and Maximum query string
   (Bytes) fields.
7. Click OK and Restart IIS

How long are the URLs you are expecting to use? If they are overly long then you may need to consider shortening your parameter names, or using a POST request instead of a GET request.

Comment: I have used POST method. Thanks for response!!